# hubConnection.on() is not working In Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, signalr, signalr.client

i am implementing SignalR on client side with android using kotlin. I can connect and can get connection id its mean connection established succeeded after that invoke  and subscribed it, when i call hubConnection.on() it could not move inside any log or nor catch any exception. where i have done mistake any help is appreciated

```
lifecycle.coroutineScope.launchWhenCreated {
       hubConnection =
            HubConnectionBuilder.create("baseurl",)
                .build()
        hubConnection.start().blockingAwait()


        Log.e("123**** ", "Established  connection......" + hubConnection.connectionId)
        val userID = "Model.user_id"

        try {
        hubConnection.invoke(
                "Subscribe",
                hubConnection.connectionId,
                arrayListOf(
                    userID,
                    "$userID+_messaging",
                    "$userID+_notification",
                    "$userID+_setting",
                    "$userID+_plan",
                    "$userID+_refresh"
                )
            ).subscribe()
            
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ExceptionDone: ", e.toString())
        }
        
        try {
            hubConnection.on("ReceiveSimplifiedRealTime", { response: String ->
               // runOnUiThread {
               Log.e("Receive123**** ", response)
                //}
            }, String::class.java)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Receive123**** ", e.toString())
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            Log.e("Receive123**** ", e.toString())
        }
    }
```